# set same navigation bar in xib and storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a Project In which I have FrontViewController And SlideOutMenu. On clicking MenuItem I want according view in the FrontViewController's subview.  
The FrontViewController is having Storyboard and all the subviews are created in `.xib`. And I am getting subview but not getting the navigation bar as in the Storyboard.

So my question is:

How to get the same navigation bar in the xib as the storyboard has?

I have tried:

```
   UINavigationController *navigationController =
         [[UINavigationController alloc]
         initWithRootViewController:bookingViewController]; 

   [_swReveal
   pushFrontViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

But I am not getting anything.

---

Comment: navigation controller embed in with your story board?

Comment: Yes, I have added it.

Comment: Can you please add the screenshot?

Comment: Currently I am not able to add the screen shots . But imagine the storyboard's nav bar with Its title and bar button item . That is what i want is .xib( inheriting the nav bar in xib from storyboard ) .